# Nextjs: Props object undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, undefined

Goal: to map over 'portfolio' projects stored in a local json file, and pass each object to a card component i created.

The portfolio component is in the pages folder, and the console.log(line: 15 - correctly displays array of json objects // [ {}, {}, {} ]...

```js
import React from "react"
import Card from "../components/Card"
    
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await import("./db.json")
    return {
        props: {
            projects: res.projects,
        },
    }
}
```

```
const portfolio = ({ projects }) => {
    //this console.log works as expected
    console.log(projects)
    return (
        <div className='portfolio'>
            {projects.map((project, id) => (
                <Card key={id} props={project} /> 
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
    
export default portfolio
```

the issue began when attempting to destructure the props object passed to the card component. The first thing i noticed were no images, but upon closer inspection: no title, no working links, etc. i receive undefined... and I'm not completely sure why.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Image from "next/image"
    
const Card = ({ image, title, github, demo }) => {
    console.log(title)
    const [hovered, setHover] = useState(false)
    return (
        <div
            className='portfolio-card'
            onMouseEnter={() => setHover(!hovered)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setHover(!hovered)}
        >
            <div className='portfolio-card-info'>
                <h3 className='portfolio-card-title'>{title}</h3>
                {hovered && <p>ReactJs</p>}
                {hovered && <p>Recoil</p>}
                <ul className='portfolio-links'>
                    <li>
                        <a href={github}>Source</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href={demo}>Demo</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <Image className='portfolio-image' src={image} alt='portfolio-image' />
        </div>
    )
}
    
export default Card
```

the console.log from portfolio: 15: 10 shows the array of objects as expected.

the console.log from card: 5:10 is undefined.

[Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ] portfolio:15:10

undefined                   Card.js:5:10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtQkl.png)

I checked the react dev tools, if i select the first card for example, i can see the props.can anyone tell me what i'm missing here, i've been on this now for a day and a half.

Comment: You're passing the props to the `Card` component incorrectly. Either you spread the `project` object over the props with `<Card key={id} {...project} /> ` or pass the props one by one as `<Card key={id} title={project.title} image={project.image} /> `.

Comment: @juliomalves success. i understand now what my problem was. Not allowing me to mark as answered.